# Buetooth connection failed: read failed, socket might closed or timeout, read ret: -1

Tags: java, android, bluetooth

I am trying to create a **Bluetooth connection**.

I can search for nearby devices but when I try to connect I get an error I do not understand:

## LOGCAT

```
01-03 00:55:06.909 6654-6654/com.bluetooth.prova3.listdiscovery D/CONNECTTHREAD: Could not close connection:java.io.IOException: read failed, socket might closed or timeout, read ret: -1
```

I Have two classes for connect, one that receives the device and execute the connection, an other for make connection.

**ConexionActivity.Java**

```
package com.bluetooth.prova3.listdiscovery;

***Imports*****

public class ConexionActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_conexion);

        //Aqui rebo el dispositiu que he seleccionat per conectarme
        Intent intent = getIntent();
        BluetoothDevice bluetoothDevice = intent.getExtras().getParcelable("btdevice");
        //mostro el nom per la pantalla amb un text view
        TextView MacAddress = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.MAC);
        String aaaa = bluetoothDevice.getName() + "\n" + bluetoothDevice.getAddress();
        MacAddress.setText(aaaa);

        ConnectThread conexion = new ConnectThread(bluetoothDevice);
        conexion.run();
    }
}
```

**ConnectThread.java**

```
package com.bluetooth.prova3.listdiscovery;
```

***Imports***

```
public class ConnectThread extends Thread{
    private final BluetoothSocket mmSocket;
    private final BluetoothDevice mmDevice;
    UUID UUIDaleatorio = UUID.randomUUID();
    public ConnectThread(BluetoothDevice device) {
        // Use a temporary object that is later assigned to mmSocket,
        // because mmSocket is final
        BluetoothSocket tmp = null;
        mmDevice = device;

        // Get a BluetoothSocket to connect with the given BluetoothDevice
        try {
            // MY_UUID is the app's UUID string, also used by the server code
            tmp = device.createRfcommSocketToServiceRecord(UUIDaleatorio);
        } catch (IOException e) {

            Log.d("CONNECTTHREAD", "Could not close connection:" + e.toString());
        }
        mmSocket = tmp;
    }

    public void run() {
        // Cancel discovery because it will slow down the connection
        //mBluetoothAdapter.cancelDiscovery();
       try {
            // Connect the device through the socket. This will block
            // until it succeeds or throws an exception
            mmSocket.connect();
        } catch (IOException connectException) {
           Log.d("CONNECTTHREAD", "Could not close connection:" + connectException.toString());
            // Unable to connect; close the socket and get out
            try {
                mmSocket.close();
            } catch (IOException closeException) { Log.d("CONNECTTHREAD", "Could not close connection:" + closeException.toString());}
            return;
        }

        // Do work to manage the connection (in a separate thread)
       // manageConnectedSocket(mmSocket);
    }

    /** Will cancel an in-progress connection, and close the socket */
    public void cancel() {
        try {
            mmSocket.close();
        } catch (IOException e) { }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 33, accepted):

Try to use ,

`createInsecureRfcommSocketToServiceRecord(MY_UUID)`

in place of

`createRfcommSocketToServiceRecord(MY_UUID)`

This should fix the problem. Share your debugging results , if this doesn't fix the issue.

Also , don't generate random UUID(s), try the one below.

`UUID MY_UUID = UUID.fromString("00001101-0000-1000-8000-00805F9B34FB");`

Comment: prateek, thanks for answer, but I get the same error in logcat.

Comment: UUID MY_UUID = UUID.fromString("00001101-0000-1000-8000-00805F9B34FB"); , try using this UUID .

Comment: Ok, That's work! Thanks! The problem was in randomUUID()?

Comment: how to upvote? :) I'm new in stackOverflow.. 
I less than15 reputation

Comment: I can't with 8 of reputation.. need 15 :(  I will be back ;)

Comment: @Prateek Thanks, it's fixed my issue

Comment: It hasn't fixed anything for me and I am not generatiing GUID but using same one you are

Answer (score 6):

This worked for me..

```
final String PBAP_UUID = "0000112f-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb";
mmSocket=device.createInsecureRfcommSocketToServiceRecord(ParcelUuid.fromString(PBAP_UUID).getUuid());

        // mmSocket = device.createRfcommSocketToServiceRecord(uuid);
           Log.d("Connection","Created");
        try {
            mmSocket.connect();
                    Log.d("Connection","Connected");

                }catch (Exception e){
                    if(mmSocket != null) {
                        try {
                            mmSocket.close();
                        } catch (IOException e1) {

                    Log.e("Connection","Socket close Error"+e1.getMessage());
                        }
                        mmSocket = null;
                    }
                    e.printStackTrace();
                    Log.e("Connection","Genmral Error "+e.getMessage());
                }
```

Comment: this solution works on xiaomi, for some reason using SPP UUID it doesn't work on my Xiaomi

Answer (score 2):

I tied all solutions in the post, but without success. The error still appeared:

```
java.io.IOException: read failed, socket might closed or timeout, read ret: -1
            at android.bluetooth.BluetoothSocket.readAll(BluetoothSocket.java:772)
            at android.bluetooth.BluetoothSocket.waitSocketSignal(BluetoothSocket.java:725)
            at android.bluetooth.BluetoothSocket.accept(BluetoothSocket.java:499)
            at android.bluetooth.BluetoothServerSocket.accept(BluetoothServerSocket.java:171)
            at android.bluetooth.BluetoothServerSocket.accept(BluetoothServerSocket.java:157)
            at com.milen.bluetoothapp.services.MyBluetoothService$AcceptThread.run(BluetoothConnectionService.kt:71)
```

I got success when I changed `createInsecureRfcommSocketToServiceRecord(MY_UUID)` whit this:

```
private inner class ConnectThread(device: BluetoothDevice) : Thread() {
    
        private var bluetoothSocket: BluetoothSocket? = device.javaClass.getMethod(
            "createRfcommSocket", Int::class.javaPrimitiveType
        ).invoke(device, 1) as BluetoothSocket?
...
}
```

Yeah, it is a hacky-reflection way, but it could save someone's life ;).
In Java it would look like this:

```
BluetoothSocket tmp = mmDevice.getClass().getMethod("createRfcommSocket", new Class[] { int.class } ).invoke(device, 1);
```

By the way, I found the solution in one opensource Github project [here](https://github.com/johnhowe/BlueTerm)

Answer (score 1):

Always check that your device is paired! Failure causes the same error.

```
BluetoothDevice device = adapter.getRemoteDevice("11:22:33:44:55:66");
if (device.getBondState()!=BluetoothDevice.BOND_BONDED)
{
   // Log or Toast
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I too struggled with this error for a while. Below is what finally works for me (in Kotlin):

MainActivity.kt:

```
import android.bluetooth.BluetoothAdapter
import android.bluetooth.BluetoothDevice
import android.bluetooth.BluetoothSocket
import android.content.Intent
import android.os.Bundle
import android.os.ParcelUuid
import android.util.Log
import android.widget.Button
import android.widget.TextView
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity


class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

    private val requestCode = 101

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)
        connectBluetooth()
    }

    private fun connectBluetooth() {

        val bluetoothAdapter = BluetoothAdapter.getDefaultAdapter()

        if (!bluetoothAdapter.isEnabled) {
            val enableBtIntent = Intent(BluetoothAdapter.ACTION_REQUEST_ENABLE)
            startActivityForResult(enableBtIntent, requestCode)
        }

        val pairedDevices = bluetoothAdapter.bondedDevices

        if(pairedDevices.isNotEmpty()){
            val device: BluetoothDevice = pairedDevices.first()
            val connectThread = Thread(ConnectThread(device))
            findViewById<TextView>(R.id.textView).text = device.name
            findViewById<Button>(R.id.connectBtn).setOnClickListener{ connectThread.run() }
            findViewById<Button>(R.id.disconnectBtn).setOnClickListener{ connectThread.run() }
        }
    }


    private inner class ConnectThread(device: BluetoothDevice) : Thread() {

        private val uuid: ParcelUuid = ParcelUuid.fromString("0000112f-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb")
        private val mmSocket: BluetoothSocket = device.createInsecureRfcommSocketToServiceRecord(uuid.uuid)

        override fun run() {
            try {
                if(mmSocket.isConnected) mmSocket.close() else mmSocket.connect()
                Log.d("Bluetooth Activity", "Socket is connected: ${mmSocket.isConnected}")
            } catch (ex: Exception) {
                Log.e("Bluetooth Activity", ex.toString())
            }
        }
    }
}
```

activity_main.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="No device connected"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/connectBtn"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginEnd="48dp"
        android:text="Connect"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/textView"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.501" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/disconnectBtn"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="64dp"
        android:text="Disconnect"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/textView"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.498" />

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```