# How to Develop a flutter chat Application Offline?

Tags: flutter, bluetooth, chat

I'm trying to develop a flutter application with feature chat offline without internet

[Bluetooth serial](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_bluetooth_serial)  and [blue](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_blue)  packages have been tried as below:

1. list paired devices successfully.
2. create socket with remote device successfully.
3. connect to that device(mobile) failed,couldn't establish connection with tis socket, only works with serial board devices like Arduino.

**always getting this : **
"read failed, socket might closed or timeout, read ret: -1"

Would you please recommend alternate ways and which is the best and applicable ?

```html
Future<void> connect(String address) async{
    try {
      BluetoothConnection connection = await BluetoothConnection.toAddress(address);
      print('Connected to the device');

      connection.input!.listen((Uint8List data) {
        print('Data incoming: ${ascii.decode(data)}');
        connection.output.add(data); // Sending data

        if (ascii.decode(data).contains('!')) {
          connection.finish(); // Closing connection
          print('Disconnecting by local host');
        }
      }).onDone(() {
        print('Disconnected by remote request');
      });
    }
    catch (exception) {
      print('Cannot connect, exception occured');
      print(exception.toString());
    }
 }
```

Comment: Can you include the code-snippet that will reproduce the same issue you are facing ?

Comment: @YeasinSheikh ,done, it is included

Comment: [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/36785985/10157127)  may help

Comment: I found the solution by using nearby connection better than using Bluetooth , here is the src code 
https://github.com/HajerWael/offline-flutter-nearby-chat-app